# variable en cuerpo de html

Tags: vb.net

puedo enviar el correo pero el cuerpo del mensaje no aparece, solo la imagen que coloco como logo de la empresa, mi pregunta es si en la linea: Dim htmlBody As String = ""
puedo colocar la variable mensaje del Richtextbox, de forma tal que muestre en el correo la imagen de logo de la empresa y debajo el texto del mensaje en sí.
solo se muestra la imagen en el correo el cuerpo del mensaje es texto que tengo en el richtexbox pero no se muestra en el correo.

si pudiera concatenar la variable del mensaje y

```
    Imports System.Data.SQLite
    Imports System.Net.Mail
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Net.Mime


    Public Class correo
        Private correo As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Private envio As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        Private Sub correo_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Me.Text = menuppal.titulo
            Dim logo As Image = encab
            Clipboard.SetImage(logo)
            RichTextBox1.Paste()
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            logo = pied
            Clipboard.SetImage(logo)
            RichTextBox1.Paste()
            Call cargacombo()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dispose()
        End Sub
        Sub cargacombo()
            Dim sql As String = "select correo from usuarios"
            Dim Dt As New DataTable
            Dim Da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)
            Da.Fill(Dt)
            ComboBox1.DataSource = Dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "correo"
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

            enviar()
        End Sub
        Sub enviar()
            Button2.Enabled = False
            Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("sauriodont@gmail.com", "calculatu1")
            Smtp_Server.Port = 587
            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
            '
            Dim mensaje As String = Me.RichTextBox1.Text
            Dim htmlBody As String = "<html><body><img src=""cid:Pic1"" ></a></body></html>"
            Dim avHtml As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
            Dim pic1 As New LinkedResource(("encabezado2.jpg"), MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
            pic1.ContentId = "Pic1"
            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(pic1)

            '
            Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            Dim de As String = Me.ComboBox1.Text
            Dim para As String = TextBox1.Text
            e_mail = New MailMessage
            e_mail.From = New MailAddress(de)
            e_mail.To.Add(para) 'correo destino
            e_mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            '
            e_mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml)
            'e_mail.Body = mensaje
            '
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
            MsgBox("Su mensaje ha enviado con exito")
            Button2.Enabled = True
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            RichTextBox1.Text = ""
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Espero que ese no sea el password real de tu usuario. mas alla de eso, donde estas agregando el texto al correo?

Comment: lo estoy colocando en un richtextbox lo paso a string en la variable mensaje

Comment: Pero dices que tu mail es html, y sin embargo no veo donde estas agregando el mensaje al html para mostrarlo.. creo que ahi esta tu problema..

Comment: si puedes por favor ser un poquito mas explicito, el codigo funciona bien solo que no muestra el texto del richtextbox, solo muestra la imagen del logo. lo que deseo hacer es que muestre el logo arriba y luego el texto del richtextbox, el cual esta en la variable mensaje

Comment: lo que deseo hacer es incluir mensaje como variable en la linea de codigo html                                                                                          Dim mensaje As String = Me.RichTextBox1.Text
            Dim htmlBody As String = "<html><body><img src=""cid:Pic1"" ></a></body></html>"